# Direct value transfer instead of select copy/paste between workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm able to select copy/paste between workbooks using recorded macros. It's working. BUT, as reading I'm learning there is a faster way that doesn't involve the copy/paste clipboard. Hope someone can help teach me to fish.

Let me explain what's going on.

- Excel with main workbook open, goto FILE OPEN then open text file.
- Walk thru the text delimited section.
- With new text workbook open select ("A2:G2000") hit COPY.
- Go back to main excel file, find your worksheet, find your Range("B6:H6") hit PASTE.

That's it.

I rounded the rows at 2000 because it is a safe bet data will not travel pass this row.  However, I know there is a better way.  Currently, I'm getting a 438 error Object doesn't support this property or method.  Maybe you can help shed some light on this.

I'm going to attach a copy of my vba code with rem statements walking thru the process. Thank you in advance.  I'm just learning the stackoverflow setup and hope I can pay it forward.  Thank You,  Boomer

```
    `Sub import_data()
    '
    ' import_data Macro
    Dim wb1 As Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Using FILE-OPEN text file and run thru text delimited setup

  Workbooks.OpenText (Module33.FileDir + "\cf_data.txt"), Origin:=437, _
  StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
  ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False _
  , Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), _
  Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1)), 
  TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

        'Applying the newly open excel workbook (text file)to a variable wb1
  Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook

         'Switching to the first sheet within this wb1 workbook
  With wb1.Sheets(1)

         'Selecting Columns A thru G and all rows in each columns that have 
          'values. text or numbers, no formulas.
  lr = .Range("A:G").Find(what:="*", after:=.Range("A1"), 
  searchorder:=xlByRows, _
  searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
  .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(lr, "G")).Value          '<====Run-time 438 '- Object doesn't support this property or method

  End With

  wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False

        'Switches back to main workbook to sheet 2 then range B6 and paste 
        'all data

  Workbooks("Auto_Data.xlsm").Sheet2.Range("B6").Resize(UBound(arr, 
        1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr


    'The code below does what I'm wanting however, it is very sluggish. This 
    'code, when in use, will sit just below text delimited section.

'    Range("A2:G2000").Select
'    Selection.Copy
'    Windows("Auto_Data.xlsm").Activate
'    Sheet2.Select
'    Range("B6:H6").Select
'    ActiveSheet.Paste
'    Selection.AutoFilter
'    Application.CutCopyMode = False
'    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
'    ActiveWindow.Close
'    Range("B4").Select


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

So here's a simple example for you to adapt to your needs. What you have to be careful of is to make clear your references to which workbook, worksheet, and range. In this example, the only thing that's copied is the data. Using copy/paste is better suited to copying both the data and the embedded formatting (which won't apply to your situation).

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportData()
    Dim destWB As Workbook
    Set destWB = ThisWorkbook

    Dim textWB As Workbook
    Dim textWS As Worksheet
    Workbooks.OpenText "C:\Temp\testdata.txt", Space:=True
    Set textWB = ActiveWorkbook
    If textWB Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Unable to open the text data"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set textWS = textWB.Sheets(1)
    End If

    '--- determine the data range and copy to a memory-based array
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    Dim textArea As Range
    Dim textData As Variant
    With textWS
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set textArea = .Range("A1").Resize(lastRow, lastCol)
        textData = textArea
    End With

    Dim destWS As Worksheet
    Dim destArea As Range
    Set destWS = destWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set destArea = destWS.Range("A1").Resize(lastRow, lastCol)
    destArea = textData

    textWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

> **EDIT:** updated the answer to address the OP's questions from the
>   comments.

```
Sub ImportData2()
    Dim destWB As Workbook
    Set destWB = ThisWorkbook

    Dim textWB As Workbook
    Dim textWS As Worksheet
    Workbooks.OpenText "C:\Temp\testdata.txt", Space:=True
    Set textWB = ActiveWorkbook
    If textWB Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Unable to open the text data"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set textWS = textWB.Sheets(1)
    End If

    Dim destWS As Worksheet
    Set destWS = destWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '--- first range to copy A2:A<lastRow> to destWS A2
    CopyData textWS, 1, 1, destWS, "A2"

    '--- second range to copy E2:E<lastRow> to destWS E2
    CopyData textWS, 5, 1, destWS, "E2"

    '--- third range to copy G2:J<lastRow> to destWS G2
    CopyData textWS, 7, 4, destWS, "G2"

    textWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub

Private Sub CopyData(ByRef srcWS As Worksheet, _
                     ByVal startColumn As Long, _
                     ByVal numberOfColumns As Long, _
                     ByRef destWS As Worksheet, _
                     ByVal destCell As String)
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim textArea As Range
    Dim textData As Variant
    With srcWS
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, startColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        Set textArea = .Cells(2, startColumn).Resize(lastRow, numberOfColumns)
        textData = textArea
    End With

    Dim destArea As Range
    Set destArea = destWS.Range(destCell).Resize(textArea.Rows.Count, _
                                                 textArea.Columns.Count)
    destArea = textData
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You PeterT, I appreciate your information.  I swear someday this is going to make sense to me.  I understand your variables and believe I can keep them straight. But my troubles are going to lie with the range entries. ?,. With my example being ("A2:G2000"), Within your [ WITH textWS ] statement would I plug my lastCol setting as 7? Column A thru G is 7 columns. Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: And with the [  Set textArea = .Range("A2") ] the textArea will count over 7 columns starting with row (2,A)? I believe the last ? is, with your lastRow & lastCol statements, this will check for data going UP from the bottom of each columns? Is this correct thinking?  My lightbulb is DIM and I know enough to really mess something up.  lol   Thanks Again for helping me with this. I do appreciate it.

Comment: Hello PeterT,  After working thru the workbook/sheet/ textdata referencing it seems that I have made my first completed successful transfer from textData to destArea.  You were right at it being tricky.  And placement of code is key. I have work thru all of my ranging issues to make the transfer work. But I'm excited about trying some more of this.  I believe it should make the process more efficient.  ? for you....Since this bit of code is great for bulk data transferring, could it be used for multiple columns that are not consecutive?  I think I could see  work for this but very lengthy.

Comment: I'm glad you got it to work. Yes, my code automatically figures out the size (rows and columns) of the data range you're working with. You can perform a very similar process for copying multiple, non-contiguous columns. You could, for example, get columns A-E in the `textArea` and copy to `textData` then set up your `destArea` and copy as above. Then repeat the same process for another set of columns (e.g. L-P, then R-S, W-Z). Each set of columns is a separate step.

Comment: This is AWESOME!!!!!  I am all over this!!!!   Now it's got my mind thinking about using this for the deleting of the sheet data as well.  The block of data we are importing will also (or could be deleted). There is a macros for this now.  And works really fast. I think it's fast because it's just deleting within the workbook the 25 sheets that I have listed.  However,I originally used a recorded macro for this.  There are several SELECT statements and clearcontents of the selection.  I bet with what you have shown me, I could get rid of those extra SELECT statements as well.  Thank You Much!

Comment: Ok PeterT,  I got way too happy way too fast.  I have maneuvered this code around so many ways my head is splitting.  As I mentioned earlier, I have a textWS that has multiple columns.  I just need column "A" starting at cell A2 and down to bottom. And in this case Column "E" starting at cell E2 and down to bottom. When I plug your code in, it is designed to pickup all columns to the right using xlLeft. and that's what it's doing. I've taken out some and the best I can get is returning Cell A2 and Cell E2 individually.  Your code makes sense but I think I'm over analyzing.  Code pasted above.

Comment: Hey PeterT, I have made a step or two forward and 2-3 steps back it seems.  I pasted a second set of WITH statements above. It reflect my attempt to copy one column "A" with plain variables (lastCol, lastRow, etc...) and this section of this WITH statement works. and transfer data correctly.  BUT, my second WITH statement breaks in the 3rd line [ lastRow2 = .Cells(Rows.Count, lastCol2).End(xlUp).Row ] with a runtime - 1004 error.  I do have Dim's for the extra variables.  Let me know when you have a moment.  I apprecaite it much.!!

Comment: Try my above untested edits. While I wasn't able to check it out myself, it should give you the general idea.

Comment: Hey PeterT,  I was late today getting to this project, my bad not getting back to you earlier.  I have place a bit of your code into the procedure and as soon as I F8 starting at 1st line Sub() it errors and breaks out.  Compile error: sub or function not defined and Hi-lights the [ CopyData ] statement only. I have pasted the code above. Also to mention, I have all Dim's listed as you have.  Also a bit confused by your second procedure within the code above? Is this two separate examples?  Just asking.  I'll get this, I'm just trying to sound it out.  Thanks

Comment: So above, this code starts just after the textWB opens up.  So just to finish. As soon as I start to run code I get the error compile error on the word [ CopyData ] only. ??? also have a outside ? for you. When running a procedure (F8) and stepping thru, what would cause the procedure to just bounce out and start another procedure without error or breaking?  I was just testing different pieces to get this to work and had one column "A" transferring over fine using destArea = textData.  and then next the code jumps to another procedure, no calls, no other code, nothing? Any thoughts?  Thanks

Comment: My second example uses two Subs: `ImportData2` and `CopyData`. You need to put both of those in a single module for this to work. My example had no issues compiling and running as is. What you can do is to copy those two subs and then change the part opening the text file and see how it works then.

Comment: Outside question question revised:  I have a outside ? for you.  In testing this column data transfer and putting pieces of code together, Why would the procedure jump to running the [ Sheet ] procedures that exist? It's like a GOTO statement is listed but is not.  When it's completed with the sheet's procedure code, it jumps back into the procedure and finishes up the rest of the code.  No errors/breaks nothing. Just weird.

Comment: I don't know what [ Sheet ] procedure you're referring to. If you have a `Worksheet_Change` method in the worksheet, that will certainly run. Look up Excel events and take a look at [this](https://powerspreadsheets.com/excel-vba-events/) and [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Events.aspx)

Comment: Testing has completed... BINGO!!!  I just learned that you can call another procedure while in a procedure, How to copy columns from WB to WB without using copy/select/paste, and a few different range and variable usage.  I really like the (F8) step thru. Seeing it as it happens has helped a bunch.  And separating it into two procedures actually makes more sense to me.  A LOT better than some of the other code snippets I was trying to piece together.  Thanks a Bunch.  Work like a charm!!!!

Comment: Oh, regards to the Question.  By using (F8) and stepping thru this process, I can see that this is happening every time I run this column procedure. Start (F8), open text file, 1st CopyData call, run CopyData Sub(), Jump to worksheet module and run procedure, back to 2nd CopyData call, run CopyData Sub() again, Jump to worksheet module and run procedure again, and now back to last three lines of our code textWB.Close, AutoFilter stuff, screenupdating=true, END Sub.    ****I'm sorry I'm explaining it like this.  Just wanted you to kinda understand the flow......

Comment: The sheet that we are copying these columns onto is labeled (Sheet7) and I have two command buttons on the page. I also have a small procedure that assigns a value to a cell and if that value is 1 then buttons are visible, if value is 0 then not visible.  For some reason while trying to copy these columns, vba is jumping to the worksheet (Sheet7) Code and running. I don't know enough to speak savvy about it.  I hope that make some sense.  Thank you Peter so much for hanging with me thru this. Parts of this vba that seems easy, just enough to pull you in.  Then it confuses you !!!! Thanks Again

Comment: Just impressive!!!!!  I can apply the top Sub procedure to each of my worksheets and reuse your 2nd sub procedure.  Absolutely Awesome!!!  This saves SO MUCH time....Thank you Peter for helping me through this.  I will try to keep learning so I can pay it forward to another.  I appreciate your help.